# SQL script error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with this script:

[image]

```
    UPDATE Orders AS o 
    SET o.menuId = 14259 
    WHERE o.menuId = 14422 
    AND o.userId = 
    (SELECT Id FROM users where Group = 
    (SELECT Id FROM groups where eatGroupId = 4))
```

error: Subquery returns more than 1 row // Because there are many groups and users. Does anyone know if it's somehow possible to make this query work? Or other alternatives?

Comment: Use joins for update

Comment: @JayShankarGupta, depends on dbms... ANSI SQL has no join update.

Comment: please add tag of dbms

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. Formatted text, not images.

Comment: Try to use "IN" operator place of the equal operator after o.userID and Group

Comment: your inner query returns more than 1 row. so first run the inner query separately and if you want the outer table updated for  all those values then use "IN" in where clause instead of "="

Comment: thank you all for help :) JOIN solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Orders 
SET menuId = 14259 
WHERE menuId = 14422 
AND userId IN 
(SELECT Id FROM users where Group IN
(SELECT Id FROM groups where eatGroupId = 4))
```

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

modify your query to update all the users under Group 4 is :

```
UPDATE Orders AS o 
SET o.menuId = 14259 
WHERE o.menuId = 14422 
AND o.userId IN 
(SELECT Id FROM users where Group = 
(SELECT Id FROM groups where eatGroupId = 4))
```

or to update top 1 row use:

```
UPDATE Orders AS o 
SET o.menuId = 14259 
WHERE o.menuId = 14422 
AND o.userId = 
(SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM users where Group = 
(SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM groups where eatGroupId = 4))
```

Comment: first query will update the records in specific group. Second query will update only one record.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN` operator which allows multiple value in `WHERE` cluase and do the `JOIN`s in *subquery*

```
UPDATE Orders 
SET menuId = 14259 
WHERE menuId = 14422 AND 
userId IN (
    SELECT u.Id FROM users u
    INNER JOIN groups g ON g.Id= u.Group
    WHERE g.eatGroupId = 4)
```

Comment: I have to update all records in one, subquery is not good but inner is nice way

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
 UPDATE Orders AS o 
    SET o.menuId = 14259 
    WHERE o.menuId = 14422 
    AND o.userId = 
    (SELECT Id FROM users where Group = 
    (SELECT Id FROM groups where eatGroupId = 4 group by Id) group by Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers.

Solved by:

```
  UPDATE Orders AS o 
    JOIN users u on u.Id=o.userId
    JOIN groups g on g.Id=u.Group
    SET o.menuId = 14259
    WHERE o.menuId = 14422 
    AND g.eatGroupId = 4;
```